# Reproduction Number (R0) of Agent Based Simulation (NetLogo) for COVID19 spread

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I am trying to calculate R0 of a model similar to "VIRUS" model in the Netlogo models library.

I referred to code of "EpiDEM Basic" in the models library to get an idea on how to find R0, but I couldn't understand how it works.

My second option was to calculate R0 manually from using the equation: R0 = Infectiousness *(beta)* / Recovery rate ( gemma).

> In  a  completely  susceptible  population,  the  number  of  new infections produced by the index case is equal to the effective contact rate times the average infectious period ×1/ which, by definition is R0

But, I am not clear whether to pick the value in "chance-to-recover" slider of 1/duration.

Any guidance on a Netlogo code or a manual method (eg: with excel) to calculate R0?

Comment: Are you wanting the theoretical R0 from the formula? In which case chance-to-recover is just the NetLogo name for recovery rate. But you still need to know infectiousness (probability of infecting a person each time step). Or you can calculate effective-R instead of R0 and simply count the number of agents each agent infects.

Comment: Yes @JenB . Thank you I will use the value from the chance-to-recover slider. I am using the value on the "infectiousness slider" for infectiousness. Is there a way to track the number each agent infect?

Comment: To track the number each agent infects, you need to actually edit the code. Each turtle would need a variable, and you could simply increment that counter when there is a successful transmission.

Comment: Thank you @JenB. I will try to code that.